# How to Use Alexa & Raspberry Pi switch things wirelessly?

Tags: smart-home, alexa, raspberry-pi, wireless, wemo

I wanted to use my Amazon Echo Dot to connect to my Raspberry Pi, and have it turn on switches wirelessly.

**What I have done:** I have been able to use [Makermusings's Fauxmo](https://github.com/makermusings/fauxmo) and a [relay board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KTELP3I) to "trick" Alexa to think that the Raspberry Pi is a [Wemo](http://www.belkin.com/us/Products/home-automation/c/wemo-home-automation/) device, and switch things on and off. However, that limits one to set all of the desired devices around a single area that is close to the Raspberry Pi.

**I wanted to do the following:**

1. Say command: "Alexa, turn on lamp"
2. Alexa sends command to Raspberry Pi through Fauxmo
3. Raspberry Pi turns on a switch far away that may be in the kitchen, but would use some sort of wireless switch

**Question:** How can I control a switch wirelessly through Alexa/Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Why not just ask Alexa how to do this? Or better yet, say command: "Alexa, talk to that Raspberry Pi, and turn on that switch." "Oh, and ask Fauxmo to help out if he's needed."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Buy sonoff switches
- Flash with MQTT firmware (https://github.com/arendst/Sonoff-Tasmota)
- Add to wifi
- Send MQTT messages from the Pi to control the switch

You can also use something like [Node-RED](http://nodered.org/) (comes pre installed in raspbian) and the [node-red-contrib-alexa-home-skill](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-alexa-home-skill) (I wrote this node) to send the messages and have more control than just the actions that Wemo supports.